# Check which optgroup has been clicked in jQuery Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if the provided `option` parameter in the `onChange` callback function represents the `optgroup MyGroup` element.

When I explore `option` in the Chrome debugger I get the following output which I don't understand:
[image]

Information I found in internet regarding `n.fn.init` tells me that the object hasn't been instantiated yet and therefore it is displayed in that way. My knowledge in Javascript/jQuery is too poor to understand it and fix this issue on my own.

**My Question:**

How do I have in the `onChange` function access the `option` parameter?

It would for example help me when I assign an `id` to the `optgroup` and this `id` is returned and I can check it easily.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap onChange Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').multiselect(
                {
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                    onChange:                 function(option, select)
                    {
                        // how to access option.???
                    }
                }
            )
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="example" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="MyGroup" id="MyGroupId">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`option` in your function parameters is potentially an array of jQuery objects.

Because `option` in this example can be an array of options that changed due to the selection of an `optgroup` you need to iterate or [Map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) the array and extract the information you need.

In this example an array of the option values is outputted to the console.

**Edited** as requested this example now outputs an array of option `id` also.

**Edited by Al Bundy:**

Placing the following code into the `onChange` callback function works for all possibilities. The first version from Steve0 doesn't work when `optgroup` has only 1 element. Also, my extended code - based on the original Steve0's answer - returns the `id` either for `optgroup` or the `item` depending which one was clicked:

`optionId = Array.isArray(option)
   ? $(option[0]).closest("optgroup").attr("id") 
   : option.attr("id");`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap onChange Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').multiselect(
                {
                    enableClickableOptGroups: true,
                    onChange:function(option, checked, value)
                    {
                        //console.log(option);
                        console.log($.map(option, x=>{return $(x).val();}));
                        //console.log($.map(option, x=>{return $(x).attr("id");}));
                        if(option.length > 1){
                          //if I have more than one picked, then return the ID of the first-items group
                          console.log($(option[0]).closest("optgroup").attr("id"));
                        }
                        // how to access option.???
                        //console.log($(option).val());

                        // Al Bundy extension:
                        optionId = Array.isArray(option)
                           ? $(option[0]).closest("optgroup").attr("id") 
                           : option.attr("id");
                    }
                }
            )
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="example" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="MyGroup" id='YourGroup'>
                <option id="opt1" value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option id="opt2" value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option id="opt3" value="3">Option 3</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG Steve0. I never saw this. OK, this works! I get - as you write - all changed values. Is there a way I would get the `id` of the `optgroup` if I assign one? +1 for the solution!

Comment: You need to be a little more specific.  What do you want when an optgroup is selected and what do you want when a single option is selected.

Comment: When the option `MyGroup` is clicked I need in the `onChange` callback function the `id` from the `optgroup` with the label `MyGroup` which has in my example the value `MyGroupId`. That's all.

Comment: Bingo! I can only upvote once. I will study the function `map` and `closest` you are using. I never heard of them but as I wrote my JavaScript/jQuery knowledge is poor. Thank you Steve0, good night.

Comment: I added some code to your answer. I hope you don't mind.